# iPhone - UITableView populates using plist works in Simulator but does not on iDevice

Tags: iphone, uitableview, plist, simulator, bookmarks

my problem is that im making a web browser for iPhone/iPad and i tested the bookmarked system and the tableview plist data updates when adding a bookmark. It works on the simulator side But when i tested the app using my iPhone it does not show the updates tableview I did add some data via xcode to the plist and the data i added shows up on the iPhone but still does not update to show new entries that you enter via app the plist file is called "bookmarks.plist" whats the problem ?

Here the code that writes to bookmarks.plist

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bookmarks.plist"];

if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]) {
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bookmarks" ofType:@"plist"];
    //[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:plistPath toPath:plistPath error:NULL];
}

NSMutableArray *dataRoot = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

NSMutableDictionary *item = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[item setObject: _titleField.text forKey:@"title"];
[item setObject:_urlField.text forKey:@"url"];

[dataRoot addObject:item];
[dataRoot writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Punctuation. Use it, it's good. As for your plist file, are you sure it's not "Bookmarks.plist" or something like that? iOS devices have case-sensitive file system, while iOS Simulator does not if it runs on a Mac with standard drive formatting.

Comment: the file in xcode title looks like this "bookmarks.plist"

Comment: does `plistPath` is populated or nil at runtime when running on device?

Comment: the plist (plistPath) is empty at start but should fill up when user adds a website to the file

Answer (score 0):

looks like your plist file is not in documents directory on device, neither you are copying it there at runtime (that LOC is commented).

so `plistPath` will be `nil`

if your `plistPath` is created from NSBundle, 
`[dataRoot writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];`
file will not be written as bundle resources are read-only.

this info should help you in some way.